# ios Autolayout sizeThatFits Issue With View Load Order... or Something

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

[image: sample image]

Intro:
The whole metrics table you see here is a view within a metrics viewcontroller.
There is a nearly identical table below in green (doesn't get displayed properly as you can see).
The red area and green area are actually just container UIViews for the viewcontroller's views.

The problem: I must use autolayout for my project. The size of these tables is dynamic (vertically).
It is my understanding that autolayout should be able to determine height automatically for UIViews (using intrinsicContentSize) as opposed to me manually constraining heights. The actual best height of the table in this example is 192. However, when calling sizeThatFits, it returns 405 on the viewcontroller's view. After hooking up the more button to a test method, I found that by calling sizeThatFits on the subviews of the viewcontroller's view, it properly returns a sum of 192. So, I can at least manually constrain the height by using a method to determine the sizeThatFits on the subviews, right..?

Unfortunately, this sizeThatFits method only seems to be able to work once the view has totally loaded on the screen (which explains why it works when using the "more" button test method).
If I attempt to manually determine the sizeThatFits automatically when the view loads, it returns 0 for all views. There seems to be an issue I'm not familiar with when it comes to the order of views loading or something. At what point does this method actually work?

Comment: What do you want the sizes of the two table to be -- can the first table have so many rows that it would take the whole screen? Do you want a maximum size, and then scroll to see the rest? It would be helpful to know a little more about what you want.

Comment: I'd like to handle the situation where each table can be big enough to fit all their contents (vertically) no matter how long each cell ends up being and any number of rows. So, vertically, the containing UIView of the table should be able to vertically grow and shrink between 0 and infinity. Note that this is not a UITableView. It's a collection of nested UIViews.

Comment: Where in the app did you call sizeThatFits when it returned 405?

Comment: The method that the "More" button invokes.

Comment: The table looking view is a viewcontroller. For some reason, the sizeThatFits of the view in the viewcontroller is 405. Its sizeThatFits is 0 before the screen is totally loaded just like all of its subviews. Only once the screen has loaded and the user presses the More button does sizeThatFits become anything that isn't 0.